# Como trocar de tab ao deslizar sobre a tela?

Tags: android

Tenho uma Activity que tem 2 tabs e queria saber como trocar de tab não somente ao clicar sobre uma delas, mas também quando deslizar(para a esquerda e direita) sobre a tela.

Minha activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Fragment1 frag1;
    private Fragment2 frag2;
    ActionBar bar;
    Tab tab1;
    Tab tab1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        frag1 = new Fragment1();
        frag2 = new Fragment2();

        tab1 = bar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab1");
        tab1.setTabListener(new ConfigTab(frag1, R.id.frag1));
        bar.addTab(tab1);

        tab2 = bar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Tab2");
        tab2.setTabListener(new ConfigTab(frag2, R.id.frag1));
        bar.addTab(tab2);

    }
}
```

E a classe configTab:

```
public class ConfigTab implements TabListener {
    private Fragment fragment;
    private int placeholder;

    public ConfigTab(Fragment fragment, int placeholder) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.placeholder = placeholder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.add(placeholder, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
```

Erro print na mainActivity, destacado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Print do erro ocorrido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É um pouco extenso responder à tua pergunta sem saber como é o teu código. Existe algum trabalho por trás do que pedes e esse trabalho na forma de uma resposta pode não ir ao encontro do teu caso em particular. Seria melhor colocares o código relevante na pergunta para obteres uma ajuda mais direcionada ao teu caso em particular.

Comment: @Zuul pronto postei.. as tabs então funcionando perfeitamente quando clicadas... somente queria que ao deslizar na tela trocar automaticamente as tabs.

Comment: adicionei uma foto no meu post da linha aonde ocorre o erro...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando implementei isso, fiz da seguinte forma. No layout do activity, coloquei assim:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Então o único elemento View no meu activity é o ViewPager. Para inicializar o ViewPager, no método onCreate:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Para este viewPager atribui um adapter, no caso uma classe que chamei de TabsPagerAdapter:

```
package br.com.exemplo.application.adapters;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import br.com.exemplo.presentation.views.fragments.PrimeiroFragment;
import br.com.exemplo.presentation.views.fragments.SegundoFragment;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public PrimeiroFragment primeiroFragment;
public SegundoFragment segundoFragment;


public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    primeiroFragment = new PrimeiroFragment();
    segundoFragment = new SegundoFragment();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Seu primeiro fragment
        return primeiroFragment;
    case 1:
        // Seu segundo fragment
        return segundoFragment;
    default:
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - quantidade de tabs
    return 2;
}

}
```

Voltando ao Activity, atribua o adapter ao viewPager, crie os objetos `Tab` e atribua estes à `ActionBar`:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
String[] tabs = {"Lista Publicações", "Nova Publicação"};
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        
// Adicione aqui as tabs:
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));

}
```

E também adicione um `OnPageChangeListener` ao seu viewPager:

```
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Bem, agora acredito que com o viewPager funciona. Esse `OnPageChangeListener` pode ser útil a você, porém não é obrigatório. Para os `TabListeners` implementei a interface `ActionBar.TabListener` no meu activity:

```
...
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
...
```

E com isso são criados os métodos que você usa no `ConfigTab` no activity. (Se preferir, atribua o ConfigTab como TabListener para cada objeto Tab e não implemente a interface ActionBar.TabListener):

```
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

Comment: esse seu código faz com que ao "deslizar" na tela do android pra esquerda e direita mudar os tabs?

Comment: Sim sim, irá funcionar tanto clicando sobre as tabs quanto deslizando com o dedo. Desculpe, faltou eu explicar que o método `onPageScrolled` é chamado sempre que você desliza entre tabs.

Comment: hum ok... vou tentar implementar aqui.. +1 na sua reposta.. depois que eu implementar eu marco como respondida^^ obrigado

Comment: Para fazer isso é preciso criar os objetos do tipo Tab e atribuir a cada um o TabListener mas da forma como  você fez `tab = bar.newTab()` e `bar.addTab(tab)` não daria certo neste caso. Acredito que os `TabListeners` não sejam necessarios devido o uso do `PageChangeListener` que implementa três métodos diferentes para detectar mudança de Tabs que podem ser o suficiente para seu caso.

Comment: essa linha nao da certo mAdapter.listPublicationsFragment.refreshListPublications();

Comment: Coloquei por engano, pode remove-la

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18080/discussion-between-leosantana-and-pedro-rangel).

Comment: precisa instancia o mdapter? se sim ele precisa de um fragmentmanager como fazer? pois mAdapter =  new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()); da erro

Comment: vou adicionar uma foto do erro^^

Comment: A inicialização do Adapter está correta. No erro é alegado não encontrar a classe TabsPagerAdapter, então verifique se o nome do pacote está correto. Por exemplo, no código que coloquei na primeira linha está `package br.com.exemplo.application.adapter` mas no seu projeto deve ser diferente, algo como `com.example.teste`. Verifique se o conteudo da primeira linha `package` de cada classe é realmente o mesmo que o nome do pacote.

Comment: acho q encontrei o erro.. e na biblioteca de suporte

Comment: eu estava utilizando a biblioteca v4 e deu certo em tudo... viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); não funciona da erro

Comment: era só colocar a linha if(viewPager!=null)

Comment: Fiz outra alteração no código, agora com os objetos Tab sendo criados. Observe ai logo apos apontar o adapter do ViewPager

Comment: muito boa^^ só achei estranho eu não poder utilizar a biblioteca de suporte v.13 somente a v.4

Comment: O suporte v13 engloba o v4, então se você for no diretório `libs` e excluir a biblioteca v4 não terá problema manter somente a v13.

Comment: porque na instancia de mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); sou obrigado a usa o suporte impossibilitando usar a biblioteca v13 no FragmentPagerAdapter, pois mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager()); nao funciona